# getting error while importing dbinit in python

Tags: python, mysql, database, import, module

hello I am getting error while trying to import dbinit. Is there any specefic library that I should install or download?

```
import dbinit as d
```

getting this error -

```
PS C:\Users\SRLAB-09\Desktop\movie_project> & C:/Users/SRLAB-09/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe c:/Users/SRLAB-09/Desktop/movie_project/interface.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/SRLAB-09/Desktop/movie_project/interface.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dbinit as d
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbinit'
PS C:\Users\SRLAB-09\Desktop\movie_project>
```

Comment: Are you running this in terminal or an IDE? if IDE, which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Environment only:
You need to download the dbinit package in your Virtual Environment.

Otherwise:
Check if you have dbinit downloaded in the first place. If not, download it

Comment: how to install dbinit through pip using cmd ?

Comment: Can you link the website you got this dbinit package from?

Comment: I cant seem to find dbinit site 
but I saw this package from a website while making a sql project

Comment: can you send a link to the website?